# SQL - Join 2 tables using a join column AND a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, left-join, sqlfiddle

I have a very simple request to do with **SQL Server 2008**, but I can't success to achive what I want.

**Explanation**
I have the following schema :

[image: Schema SQL]

For a given `FAVORITE`, a user can have zero or many `COMMENTs`, however, if the user have more than one comment, all `COMMENTs` have a `DeletedDate` `NOT NULL` (except possibly the last one).

`DeletedDate` acts as a Flag "IsDeleted", the application ensures that only zero or one comment per user per favorite is `NULL`. If `DeletedDate` is `NULL`, the record is considered as deleted.

But a user can have a `FAVORITE` without `COMMENT`. `COMMENT` is totally optional.


**What I'd like**

---

I'm trying to create a request, which, for a given user, will return all its valid favorites (where `FAVORITE.DeleteDate` is `NOT NULL`) and the valid `COMMENT` associated to the `FAVORITED` (if it exists).

Here is my request :

```
SELECT *
FROM FAVORITE f
LEFT JOIN COMMENT co ON f.IdReferenced = co.IdReferenced
WHERE f.IdUser = 7
  AND f.DeletedDate IS NULL
  AND co.IdUser = 7
```

*(Please use IdUser = 7 to test)*

However, this request returns all `COMMENTs` of all `FAVORITEs` of user 7, even comments where `DeletedDate` is NOT NULL.

I tried to add a `AND co.DeletedDate IS NOT NULL` to the above request, but now, it didn't return FAVORITEs which haven't any COMMENT


**FIDDLE**

---

To reproduce the problem, I created this [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/584e46/5)

**ATTEMPTED RESULTS**

---

If I wasn't clear in my explanations, the request must return FOUR rows of my SQLFIDDLE, where the CommentText field is "Must appear 1", "Must appear 2", "Must appear 3", "Must appear 4"

[image: Attempted result]

The request must return the above lines, minus the red-crossed line

**IMPORTANT**
I just made an error in my SQLFIDDLE, the fourth line of COMMENT should be

```
INSERT [dbo].[COMMENT] ([IdComment], [IdUser], [IdReferenced], [CommentText], [CreationDate], [ModificationDate], [DeletedDate]) VALUES (8, 7, 2869, N'Must appear 3', CAST(0x0000A33500EC1133 AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
```

Could you please improve my request ? I'll have to write it in LINQ, but I should be able to traduce from SQL to LINQ.
Thank you for your time !

Comment: Move all references to co out of the WHERE clause and into the JOIN condition.  Without this you are essentially "making" the LEFT OUTER JOIN into an INNER JOIN condition.

Comment: Why should the "Must appear 3" be shown?

Comment: Please check your sqlfiddle, as the data seems to be invalid

Comment: OK I'm really sorry you're right, "Must Appear3" must have DeletedDate = NULL, however I copy/pasta a datetime so itsn't null is my fiddle. Totally sorry. I will check your answers :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirement you need to put the condition for the right table (`co.DeletedDate IS NOT NULL`) in the `JOIN` portion of your query like:

```
SELECT *
FROM FAVORITE f
INNER JOIN COMMENT co ON f.IdReferenced = co.IdReferenced
AND co.DeletedDate IS NULL
AND co.IdUser = f.IdUser
WHERE f.IdUser = 7
  AND f.DeletedDate IS NULL
```

EDIT: 
In your sql fiddle the row below had a value inserted in DeletedDate. If this value is `null` the above query gives the desired result. Also have changed the '`LEFT JOIN`' to '`INNER JOIN`' in order to not show different users.

```
INSERT [dbo].[COMMENT] ([IdComment], [IdUser], [IdReferenced], [CommentText], [CreationDate], [ModificationDate], [DeletedDate]) VALUES (8, 7, 2869, N'Must appear 3', CAST(0x0000A33500EC1133 AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
```

Comment: I made an error in my data on the sqlfiddle, I'm really sorry for this. I just corrected the data, but when I execute your request, I only have two rows in the output, whereas I could have 4 (the four with a comment text "must appear"). This comment text is only here to verify the output, a solution WHERE CommentText IN (...) is obviously not I'm looking for

Comment: @AlexB, please check again, as I've made mistake by pasting. basically there was `co.DeletedDate IS NOT NULL` where should be `co.DeletedDate IS NULL`

Comment: It seems we have a winner :-) Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly. You could use `EXISTS` to check if there is such a record [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3c35a/8)

```
SELECT *
FROM FAVORITE f
LEFT JOIN COMMENT co ON f.IdReferenced = co.IdReferenced
WHERE f.IdUser = 7
  AND f.DeletedDate IS NULL
  AND  EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM COMMENT WHERE COMMENT.IdUser = co.IdUser AND co.DeletedDate IS NULL)
```

Comment: I probably wasn't very clear and I'm sorry for this. Please take a look to the "Attempted result" section of my first post I just updated. I tried with your EXISTS clause but didn't success

Answer (score 0):

This query will return all records from the favorite table, whether there is a matching comment or not(left join) and where `f.DeletedDate is not null` AND where `c.CommentText in (values)`

```
Select * from favorite f
left join comment c on c.IdReferenced = f.IdReferenced
                    and f.DeletedDate is null 
where c.CommentText in ('Must appear 1', 'Must appear 2','Must appear 3','Must appear 4')
      and f.IdUser = 7
--can use an OR statement as well
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.

Comment: It doesn't. I probably wasn't very clear, I'm sorry. Please take a look to my updated post, section "Attempted results"

Comment: It looks like you want all records where `f.DeletedDate is null`, but that's not what you said in the question

Comment: You're right and I'm sorry, one row had invalid data. I corrected it. However, "Must appear" is only a  visual check to verify if the request returns the good rows, a clause WHERE CommentText IN (...) is not what I'm looking for, you guess I didn't have such values in my real DB